# Given 200 strings, what is a good way to key a LUT of relationship values

Tags: c++, lookup-tables, unique-key

I've got 200 strings.  Each string has a relationship (measured by a float between 0 and 1) with every other string. This relationship is two-way; that is, relationship A/B == relationship B/A.  This yields n(n-1)/2 relationships, or 19,800.

What I want to do is store these relationships in a lookup table so that given any two words I can quickly find the relationship value.

I'm using c++ so I'd probably use a std::map to store the LUT.  The question is, what's the best key to use for this purpose.

The key needs to be unique and needs to be able to be calculated quickly from both words.

My approach is going to be to create a unique identifier for each word pair.  For example given the words "apple" and "orange" then I combine them together as "appleorange" (alphabetical order, smallest first) and use that as the key value.

Is this a good solution or can someone suggest something more cleverer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are describing a function of two parameters with the added property that order of parameters is not significant.

Your approach will work if you do not have ambiguity between words when changing order (I would suggest putting a coma or like between the two words to remove possible ambiguities). Any 2D array would also work.

I would probably convert each keyword to some unique identifier (using a simple map) before trying to find the relationship value, but it does not change much from what you are proposing.

Comment: +1 for a two-stage approach.  A preliminary map-to-int stage will make the second stage more efficient (for big data sets).  Of course, this may or may not be a concern...

Answer (score 1):

If boost/tr1 is acceptable, I would go for an unordered_map with the pair of strings as key.  The main question would then be: what with the order of the strings?  This could be handled by the hash-function, which starts with the lexical first string.

Remark: this is just a suggestion after reading the design-issue, not a study.

Answer (score 1):

How "quickly" is quickly? Given you don't care about the order of the two words, you could try a map like this:

```
std::map<std::set<std::string>, double> lut;
```

Here the key is a `set` of the two words, so if you insert "apple" and "orange", then the order is the same as "orange" "apple", and given `set` supports the less than operator, it can function as a key in a map. NOTE: I intentionally did not use a `pair` for a key, given the order matters there...

I'd start with something fairly basic like this, profile and see how fast/slow the lookups etc. are before seeing if you need to do anything smarter...

Answer (score 0):

If you create a sorted array with the 200 strings, then you can binary search it to find the matching indices of the two strings, then use those two indices in a 2D array to find the relationship value.

Answer (score 0):

If your 200 strings are in an array, your 20,100 similarity values can be in a one dimensional array too.  It's all down to how you index into that array.  Say x and y are the indexes of the strings you want the similarity for.  Swap x and y if necessary so that y>=x,  then look at entry i= x + y(y+1)/2 in the large array.

(x,y) of (0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(0,2),(1,2),(2,2),(0,3),(1,3)...  will take you to entry 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7...

So this uses space optimally and it gives faster look up than a map would.  I'm assuming efficiency is at least mildly important to you since you are using C++!

[if you're not interested in self similarity values where y=x, then use i = x + y(y-1)/2 instead].